# Android simple widget that launches activity

Tags: android, android-activity, widget, android-intent, launch

Hi i've never worked with widgets before but what i'm looking to do is create a very simple widget i basically want to make a 1 by 1 widget that has just an icon, just an image set as the background no text nothing just a small icon and when the icon is pressed i want to open an activity. Basically i want to make a second icon like in the app drawer in a widget form that opens another activity rather than the main one. 
Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My provider ended up looking like this after a lot of research and playing

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ClassToLaunchHere.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget, pendingIntent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of app widget implementations that show the easiest way to do that are visible at https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AppWidget.

Specifically, https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/AppWidget/PairOfDice/src/com/commonsware/android/appwidget/dice/AppWidget.java shows how to use a PendingIntent as the onClick target for a Button. You can make your PendingIntent start an Activity and you should be good to go.

Comment: Well i followed this link to make a widget added a background and removed the text etc i looked at your links and still can't figure out what exactly to put in the Provider class to launch an intent to my activity
http://androidcore.com/android-programming-tutorials/606.html

Answer (score 0):

Declare a Variable

```
public static String YOUR_AWESOME_ACTION = "YourAwesomeAction";
```

then add onUpdate and onReceive

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                     int[] appWidgetIds) {
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, DigitalClock.class);

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.digital_clock);

    for (int widgetId : appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget)) {
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageView, getPendingSelfIntent(context, YOUR_AWESOME_ACTION));
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
    }
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if (YOUR_AWESOME_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {

        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.digital_clock);
        ComponentName watchWidget = new ComponentName(context, DigitalClock.class);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(watchWidget, remoteViews);

        Intent ntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        ntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(ntent);

        //Toast.makeText(context, YOUR_AWESOME_ACTION, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, getClass());
    intent.setAction(action);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
}
```

and add activity on Manifest

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

hope this will help